# How to include firebase analytics in Angular 10 app dashboard?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, analytics, angularfire

"@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",

"@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",

Can anyone weigh in on how to create a firebase analytics dashboard?  Is it possible to retrieve firebase analytics events in an angular app and display the analytics in an app dashboard?

I have searched for examples of using AngularFireAnalyticsModule with Google Analytics but haven't found any that detail the usage.
I see screen_view logged in the console from angular-fire-analytics.js, but I'm not sure how to include this info in an app dashboard.

I've followed the [Getting started with Google Analytics](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/analytics/getting-started.mdhttps://) docs and added the code to app.module.ts:

```
import { AngularFireAnalyticsModule, CONFIG, DEBUG_MODE, ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
```

```
  imports: [
     AngularFireAnalyticsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ScreenTrackingService,
    UserTrackingService,

    { provide: CONFIG, useValue: {
        send_page_view: false,
        allow_ad_personalization_signals: false,
        anonymize_ip: true
      }
    },
    { provide: DEBUG_MODE, useValue: true }
  ],
```

I have logged a 'notification_received' event and can see the event logged on the firebase dashboard StreamView.

```
export class AnalyticsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    analytics: AngularFireAnalytics,) {
    analytics.logEvent('notification_received');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, like this in the provider config

```
providers: [ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService, 
{ provide: CONFIG, useValue: {
  DEBUG_MODE: true
} }]
```

Comment: Yes I have done that. See the code in my question. I am receiving debug output in the console. I want to capture the output and display it on a custom dashboard.

Comment: Debug console output: screen_view angular-fire-analytics.js:465 screen

Comment: I am looking for an example angular application that shows this: "AngularFireAnalytics provides a convenient method of interacting with Google Analytics in your Angular application."

Comment: Should I be interfacing with Google Analytics to access the AngularFireAnalytics "screen_view debug output" to display in a dashboard?

Comment: Link BigQuery to Firebase
Linking your Firebase project to BigQuery lets you access your raw, unsampled event data along with all of your parameters and user properties.